# Perturbation theory with Mathematica: Definite integral of polynomial times exponential times hypergeometric function of imaginary argument

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions, approximation

I would like to ask also Mathematica users about my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1115704/195194) from the math forum. To expand, I'm adding the code which calculates the full double integral for $n=0$ and $\mu=0$ (the second in the post):

```
f[r_] := r^n E^(-r (1 + μ)) E^(-I k r) Hypergeometric1F1[I/k+1,2,2 I k r]; g = f[r] /. {n -> 0, μ -> 0};

NIntegrate[k^2 Exp[π/k] Abs[Gamma[1 - I/k]]^2/(1 + k^2)Abs[Integrate[g, {r, 0, ∞}]]^2, {k, 0, ∞}]
```

giving 1.65719 which confirms the result which I obtained by another (perturbative) method.

However, as Jinxed pointed out, if one only evaluates the inner integral (over $r$), it does not converge, if one assumes $k$ to be real:

```
f[r_] := r^n E^(-r (1 + μ)) E^(-I k r) Hypergeometric1F1[I/k + 1, 2, 2 I k r]; g = f[r] /. {n -> 0, μ -> 0};Integrate[g, {r, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> {n == 0 || n == 1, μ ∈ Reals, μ >= 0, n ∈ Integers, k > 0, k ∈ Reals}]
```

Could you help me make sense of this? I appreciate any ideas!

Comment: Have you actually tried solving it in *Mathematica* ?

Comment: He says in the linked question, "Mathematica can handle this integral in about one minute if numerical values of $n$ and $\mu$ are chosen."  It would be nice if you could give us your MMA code though.

Comment: With `f[r_] := r^n E^(-r (1 + \[Mu])) E^(-I k r)
    Hypergeometric1F1[I/k + 1, 2, 2 I k r];
g = f[r] /. {n -> 0, \[Mu] -> 0};Integrate[g, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> {n == 0 || n == 1, \[Mu] \[Element] Reals, \[Mu] >= 0,
    n \[Element] Integers, k > 0, k \[Element] Reals}]` it sure does not converge.

Comment: For the assumptions given in the reference, Mathematica claims that the "Integrate` does not converge except for `mu = -1`, and indeed gives error messages for, say, `mu = 2`.  But this makes no sense, because the integrand is smaller at large `r` for larger `mu`.  Moreover, `NIntegrate` does converge for numerical values of `k` and `n`.  Perhaps, Mathematica is mishandling this integral.

Comment: @wondering: Because without assumptions for k, it is treated as complex, which you explicitly ruled out.

Comment: @Jinxed Right, that is of course an important observation. However, if I calculate the complete integral, I get a finite answer, which perfectly confirms the answer obtained by another (perturbative) method. So I am puzzled how to make sense of this. The full working code is in the updated question (it is adapted from yours and giving as result 1.65719).

Comment: Although Mathematica claims the integral as given by @Jinxed does not converge, performing the integral without restricting `k` gives a `ConditionalExpression` that is valid for real `k`!  Moreover, plugging that expression into the double integral gives `1.65719`.  I have voted to reopen the question.

Comment: Additionally, I believe that the general expression for the inner integral is `((-I)*k)^(-1 - n)*(-(k/(k - I*(1 + mu))))^(1 + n)*Gamma[1 + n]*
 Hypergeometric2F1[(I + k)/k, 1 + n, 2, (2*k)/(k - I*(1 + mu))]`.  I have not done enough to verify this, however.

Comment: @bbgodfrey The inner integral gives for $n=\mu= 0$ the ConditionalExpression `1/2 - 1/2 ((I + k)/(I - k))^(-I/k), 0 < Im[k] < 1` which is undefined for $k=0$ because of the exponent (but is valid for other real $k$, as you mentioned). However, the limit for `k -> 0` gives `1/2 - 1/(2 E^2)` for both the above ConditionalExpression and your expression (with $n=\mu= 0$) from the previous comment. Your expression looks good, but I must check more on this.

Comment: I just performed the integral numerically for `k = .01` and, even though it did not converge well, it gave the answer `0.432328`, which is close to `1/2 - 1/(2 E^2)`.  I have run a few other cases and obtained good agreement too.

Comment: @bbgodfrey The expression for the inner integral is indeed what you stated in the comment above. I posted a *Mathematica* derivation of that result.

Comment: @Jens  Innovative approach.  Although, in principal, your derivation requires that your original series be *uniformly* convergent, I assume it must be, or you would not have obtained the correct expression.  +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a rigorous way to deal with the integration problem, making use only of the assumption that the integral is convergent so that we can exchange the integration and the series expansion for the Coulomb function:

```
f[r_] := 
 r^n E^(-r (1 + μ)) E^(-I k r) Hypergeometric1F1[I/k + 1, 2, 
   2 I k r]; 
g = f[r] /. {n -> 0, μ -> 0}

(* ==> E^(-r - I k r) Hypergeometric1F1[1 + I/k, 2, 2 I k r] *)
```

This is the definition you posted. The trouble is caused by the hypergeometric function, so let's simply integrate term by term in its series expansion:

```
h = 
 g /. hype_Hypergeometric1F1 :> SeriesCoefficient[hype, {r, 0, ν}, 
     Assumptions -> ν >= 0] r^ν

(*
==> (2^ν E^(-r - 
  I k r) (I k)^ν r^ν (I/k + ν)!)/((I/
  k)! ν! (1 + ν)!)
*)

hype[ν_] = 
 Integrate[h, {r, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> k > 0 && ν >= 0]

(*
==> -((2^ν (k/(-I + k))^(1 + ν) Gamma[1 + I/k + ν])/(
 Gamma[I/k] Gamma[2 + ν]))
*)

FullSimplify[Sum[hype[ν], {ν, 0, Infinity}], k > 0]

(* ==> 1/2 - 1/2 ((I + k)/(I - k))^(-(I/k)) *)
```

This is the exact result. In this way of doing the calculation, *Mathematica* has no difficulties with the integration.

You can even do this for arbitrary parameters:

```
h = 
 f[r] /. hype_Hypergeometric1F1 :> 
   SeriesCoefficient[hype, {r, 0, ν}, 
     Assumptions -> ν >= 0] r^ν

(*
==> (2^ν E^(-I k r - r (1 + μ)) (I k)^ν r^(
 n + ν) (I/k + ν)!)/((I/k)! ν! (1 + ν)!)
*)

hype[ν_] = 
 Integrate[h, {r, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> k > 0 && ν >= 0 && μ >= 0 && n >= 0]

(*
==> ((2 I)^ν k^ν (1 + I k + μ)^(-1 - 
  n - ν) (I/k + ν)! Gamma[1 + n + ν])/((I/
  k)! ν! (1 + ν)!)
*)

FullSimplify[Sum[hype[ν], {ν, 0, Infinity}], k > 0]

(*
==> (1 + I k + μ)^(-1 - n)
  Gamma[1 + n] Hypergeometric2F1[(I + k)/k, 1 + n, 2, (2 k)/(
  k - I (1 + μ))]
*)
```

This is the general, exact solution for arbitrary values of the physical parameters $n$, $\mu$ and $k$.

**Edit to add some more explanation**

My goal was to let `h` represent a single general term in the original integrand, obtained by series expanding the problematic part of that integrand, which is `Hypergeometric1F1`.

Instead of re-typing this or copying and pasting, I use [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (`/.`) with  [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html) to insert a general series term of the hypergeometric function in place of the function itself. For such replacements, one has to specify a *pattern* that is to be replaced. For purposes of pattern matching, `Hypergeometric1F1` is just the [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Head.html) of an expression whose content is the argument list. To specify a pattern with a desired `Head`, one uses the `_` symbol ([`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blank.html)) preceding the desired `Head`. In our case, the replacement is not static in the sense that what we need to insert in place of the hypergeometric function depends on its arguments. So I need to take the expression to be replaced, and first do some manipulation on it (expand it in a series). That means I need a way to refer to this expression, and that's what the `hype` is for: it's just a name I made up that stands for the expression matching the pattern.

In terms of computer algebra, pattern matching and replacement is the central engine behind *Mathematica*, and without it we could just as well go back to tables of integrals. Mathematically, what `h` represents can be illustrated perhaps in one more step by doing (after executing the previous code)

```
Sum[h, {ν, 0, Infinity}]

(*
==> E^(-I k r - r (1 + μ)) r^n Hypergeometric1F1[1 + I/k, 2, 
  2 I k r]
*)

% == f[r]

(* ==> True *)
```

which means that `h` is indeed represents the original integrand itself, if you sum over the index $\nu$ I introduced as an auxiliary variable above.

Comment: +1 Excellent, thanks so much. As I am a beginning user, could you please explain me the structure of the part of the code where you define `h`? The problem for me is caused by `/. hype_Hypergeometric1F1 :>` and how it connects to the surrounding code. Also, what `_Hypergeometric1F1` (with the underscore) is exactly used for? Thanks!

Comment: P.S. Would it be possible to proceed with the outer integral in a similar fashion? Seems it woudn't, but maybe first I have to understand the `hype_Hypergeometric1F1`.

Comment: I just edited the answer to explain what I did in more detail.

Comment: I don't think you can easily use the analogous approach for the $k$ integral because the integrands there involve absolute squares. But in any case, that goes beyond what the original question contains. Since you're doing perturbation theory, it seems reasonable to approximate the $k$ integral first before trying anything with the exact form. Maybe I'll have an idea later...

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot that now the formulation of the question is slightly different than it was before my update (the outer integral was the second half of the problem). This means that I can accept your answer and later I can post a new question regarding the full integral - actually the result of the full double integral will be than plugged into an infinite sum, which is the ultimate goal.

Comment: You have an error in the math post linked from your question here: the hydrogen ground state doesn't have a factor of $r$ in front of the exponential. That would be $\ell=1$. The case $n=0$ in your question never actually arises. With your notation, you need $n=2$ for the ground state.

Comment: Thanks, corrected. Although I have it correctly in my calculations, I use reduced radial functions there and that made the mistake. I used the case $n=0$ for the perturbation $1/r^2$, so I needed it too. Actually, for the ground stated in the math forum question  I need $n=1$, note the Yukawa-type perturbation with $1/r$ in it. Anyway, my main concern seems to be now the case $n=1$ and general $\mu\in R$,  $\mu>0$ (for the beginning I might try $\mu\in\mathbb{N}$ if it is less difficult). If you had any idea on how to do the complete double integral, I will post another question.

Comment: P.S The gamma function from the outer integral in the original question can be replaced by $ |\Gamma{(1-{\mathrm i}/k})|^2=\pi/(k \sinh{(\pi/k)})$ but as you said, the main problem in the treatment of the full double integral is probably the absolute square of the inner integral.

Answer (score 2):

Define

```
arg = r^n Exp[-r (1 + mu + I k)] Hypergeometric1F1[1 + I/k, 2, 2 I k r]
```

Then, performing the inner integral in the Question, complete with `Assumptions`,

```
Integrate[arg, {r, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {k > 0, mu ∈ Reals, n ∈ Integers, 
  n >= 0}]
```

yields a `ConditionalExpression` with highly restrictive conditions, `n < 1 && mu == -1`

```
(*ConditionalExpression[(Sqrt[Pi]*((Gamma[(-I)/k + n]*
    Hypergeometric2F1[I/k, (I + k)/k, 1 + I/k - n, 1/2])/
     (8^(I/k)*Gamma[3/2 + I/k]*Gamma[-((2*I + k)/k)]) + 
    (Gamma[I/k - n]*Gamma[n]*Hypergeometric2F1[n, 1 + n, 1 - I/k + n, 1/2])/
     (8^n*Gamma[I/k]*Gamma[-1 - 2*n]*Gamma[3/2 + n])))/(8*(I*k)^n), 
    n < 1 && mu == -1] *)
```

Moreover, if `mu ∈ Reals` is replaced by `mu >= 0` in the `Assumptions`, Mathematica 10.0.2.0 asserts that the integral does not converge:

```
Integrate::idiv: Integral of E^(-(1+I k+mu) r) r^n Hypergeometric1F1[(I+k)/k,2,2 I k r] does not converge on {0,∞}. >>
```

This assertion seems dubious, because `arg` evaluated at mu == -1 bounds `arg` evaluated at larger values of `mu` for `r > 0`.

An alternative approach is to perform the integral without `Assumptions`

```
Integrate[arg, {r, 0, Infinity}]
```

which yields a `ConditionalExpression` with conditions such as `Im[k] > 0` that ostensibly violate the constraints imposed by the Question.

```
(* ConditionalExpression[((-I)*k)^(-1 - n)*(-(k/(k - I*(1 + mu))))^(1 + n)*Gamma[1 + n]*
     Hypergeometric2F1[(I + k)/k, 1 + n, 2, (2*k)/(k - I*(1 + mu))], 
     Im[k] > 0 && 1 + Re[n] > 0 && Im[k] <= 1 + Re[mu] && 
       (Im[k^(-1)] + Re[n] < 1 || Im[k] < 1 + Re[mu])] *)
```

So, ignore those conditions and simply assume

```
ans = %[[1]]
(* ((-I)*k)^(-1 - n)*(-(k/(k - I*(1 + mu))))^(1 + n)*Gamma[1 + n]*
     Hypergeometric2F1[(I + k)/k, 1 + n, 2, (2*k)/(k - I*(1 + mu))] *)
```

This assumption is readily tested by comparing `ans` with results of `NIntegrate` for relevant values of `n`, `mu`, and `k`.

```
Show[Plot[Evaluate[Chop@Table[ans, {n, 0, 1}, {mu, 1, 2}]], {k, .01, 5}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, .4}, ImageSize -> 400, PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[{"n=0, mu=1", "n=0, mu=2", "n=1, mu=1", "n=1, mu=2"}, 
      Scaled[{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}]]],
  ListPlot[Flatten[Table[Chop[NIntegrate[arg, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}], 10^-5], 
    {n, 0, 1}, {mu, 1, 2}, {k, {.01, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}], 1] // Quiet]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Evidently, `ans` is a valid answer even for `Im[k] = 0`, and the assertion by Mathematica cited above that the integral does not converge for `mu >= 0` is inaccurate.

For completeness, `ans` can be simplified for

```
Table[Simplify[ans], {n, 0, 1}, {mu, 1, 2}]
(* {{1/2 - 1/(2*((2*I + k)/(2*I - k))^(I/k)), 
     1/2 - 1/(2*((3*I + k)/(3*I - k))^(I/k))}, 
   {1/(((2*I + k)/(2*I - k))^(I/k)*(4 + k^2)), 
     1/(((3*I + k)/(3*I - k))^(I/k)*(9 + k^2))}} *)
```

and for larger integer values of `n` and `mu` as well.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the nice analysis. Maybe someone on the math forum suggests what could be the reason for such a behavior of the integral (and of Mathematica's treatment of it).

Comment: I have another observation, please correct me if I am wrong (I restarted Mathematica to be sure). If I make the replacement $\mu\to\mu-1$ in the integral, then the resulting (equivalent, if the assumptions are properly changed) code does not give the condition `Im[k]>0`, only `\[Mu] > Im[k]`. 
The code:
`f[r_] := r^n E^(- \[Mu] r) E^(-I k r) Hypergeometric1F1[I/k + 1, 2, 
   2 I k r]; g = f[r]; Integrate[g, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, following
 Assumptions -> {\[Mu] \[Element] Reals, \[Mu] >= 1, 
   n \[Element] Integers, n >= 0}]`
Could you please check? Did I do any mistake?

Comment: @wondering I copied and ran the code in your last comment but still get the usual conditions, ` \[Mu] >= Im[k] && Im[k] > 0 && (\[Mu] != Im[k] || n + Im[k^(-1)] < 1)`.

Comment: I wonder what causes this behavior. I tried a couple of times. Completely restarting Mathematica 10.0.0.0 gives `\[Mu] > Im[k]` with the above code (with the word "following":-), however, if I restart and add `Clear["Global`*"];` before the code, I get what you say. Strange.

Comment: @wondering   That is strange, and I have not good answer.  Sorry.